# Magento 2: How to add meta tags "NoIndex, Follow" to sitemap page

Tags: magento-2.1, sitemaps, meta-tags

I'm trying to add robots metatags "NOINDEX, FOLLOW" to the sitemap. How can we achieve it in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You can't manage it with native functionality. But you can add these tags in layout file `vendor/magento/module-sitemap/view/frontend/layout/robots_index_index.xml` or check these modules:

- https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/advanced-seo-suite.html
- https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-seo-extension.html
- https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-SEO-Extension.html